# A property associated with restricted class of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question**: Is my argument, described below, right?

Let $f(z)$ be an analytic function in a region containing the unit disc with $f(z)\neq 0$ in $|z|<1,$ and suppose for some fixed $M>0,$
$$
\Re \frac{zf'(z)}{Mf(z)}\leq \frac{1}{2}
$$ for all $z$ on $|z|=1$ for which $f(z)\neq 0.$
Then
$$
\left|1-\frac{zf'(z)}{Mf(z)}\right|\geq \left|\frac{zf'(z)}{Mf(z)}\right|
$$ for all $z$ on $|z|=1$ for which $f(z)\neq 0.$
But then
$$
|Mf(z)-zf'(z)|\geq |f'(z)|,
$$ on $|z|=1$ which further implies
$$
|Mf(z)-zf'(z)|> |\lambda f'(z)|
$$ on $|z|\leq 1$ and for any complex number $\lambda$ with $|\lambda|<1. $ Therefore for $|z|\leq 1$ and $|\lambda|<1, $

$$Mf(z)-zf'(z)-\lambda f'(z)\neq 0.$$

Comment: How did you drop $M$?

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. I think you mentioned about line -3.

Comment: You have assumed that $|\lambda f'(z)| <|f'(z)|$. This requires that $f'(z) \neq 0$. If you have $f'(z) \neq 0$ then what you have done is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is correct if you split the proof into then cases $f'(z)=0$ and $f'(z) \neq 0$. In the first case use the hypothesis that $f(z)\neq 0$ so $Mf(z)-zf'(z)-\lambda f'(z)=Mf(z) \neq 0$. In the second case your argument works fine.